# how do i set up the database to work with spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I link database and spring, application works fine. But when sending data to the database, only the structure without the data appears.

User.class

```
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;


@Entity // This tells Hibernate to make a table out of this class
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String email;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

MainController.class

```
import jakarta.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller    // This means that this class is a Controller
public class MainController {
    @Autowired // This means to get the bean called userRepository
    // Which is auto-generated by Spring, we will use it to handle the data
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @PostMapping(path="/add") // Map ONLY POST Requests
    public @ResponseBody String addNewUser (@RequestParam String name
            , @RequestParam String email) {
        // @ResponseBody means the returned String is the response, not a view name
        // @RequestParam means it is a parameter from the GET or POST request

        User n = new User();
        n.setName(name);
        n.setEmail(email);
        userRepository.save(n);
        return "Saved";
    }

    @GetMapping(path="/all")
    public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

UserRepository.interface

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Integer> {

}
```

Application.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I would be grateful if you explain what is the reason or point out the problem in the code.

as a result, when sending data, I get an empty database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj9gi.png)

Comment: Could you use a `RepositoryRestResource` like described in https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/?

Comment: No transasction, nothing int he database.

Comment: Hello, as stated before - new added data won't be seen in the SQL client until the transaction is committed. In your repository code you are using a simple CrudRepository which doesn't create any transaction at all. I suggest to use JPARepository instead. It will use transactions and commit the changes internally.

Comment: Is it a Springboot application or normal spring application since you are using @controller annotation instead of Rest Controller annotation. Also could you please put your request call for saving data and what is the response of your request as well which helps to see whether your request is missing something.

Answer (score 0):

You should just tell it what data type to return.

Change this:

```
@GetMapping(path="/all")
public @ResponseBody Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

To this:

```
@GetMapping(path="/all")
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    // This returns a JSON or XML with the users
    return userRepository.findAll();
}
```

Comment: That won't help it will actually lead to different errors.

Comment: Then return only a list of users. I think that is the standard.

Comment: That won't change a thing either. Removing `@ResponseBody` from an `@Controller` will lead to other issues, so your answer won't solve anything only make things worse.